# Random freezes followed by loss of WiFi connection with a BCM4313 wireless card

Tags: 11.04, wireless, mouse, freeze, broadcom

I did a clean install of Natty Narwhal on my AspireOne D255 Netbook. Right off the bat, it seems to work right out of box, but from time to time (especially shortly after booting up or resuming from sleep), mouse cursor would freezes, followed by a drop in WiFi connection.

Can anyone go about suggesting how to troubleshoot this annoyance?

Just some background information.
My system is not powerful enough to run Unity, so it is under classic mode at the moment.

Here is the output from lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation N10 Family DMI Bridge
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation N10 Family Integrated Graphics Controller
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation N10 Family Integrated Graphics Controller
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 02)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 1 (rev 02)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 2 (rev 02)
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 02)
00:1d.1 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 02)
00:1d.2 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 02)
00:1d.3 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 02)
00:1d.7 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 02)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev e2)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation NM10 Family LPC Controller (rev 02)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH7 Family SATA AHCI Controller (rev 02)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family SMBus Controller (rev 02)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Atheros Communications AR8152 v1.1 Fast Ethernet (rev c1)
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller (rev 01)
```

Here is the excerpt from dmesg

```
[ 8127.020293] eth1: no IPv6 routers present
[ 8154.099945] psmouse.c: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost synchronization, throwing 1 bytes away.
[ 8155.128208] psmouse.c: resync failed, issuing reconnect request
[ 8195.396010] atl1c 0000:01:00.0: atl1c: eth0 NIC Link is Up<100 Mbps Full Duplex>
[ 8195.924818] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[ 8210.300491] psmouse.c: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost synchronization, throwing 5 bytes away.
[ 8215.851447] atl1c 0000:01:00.0: irq 45 for MSI/MSI-X
[ 8217.129771] atl1c 0000:01:00.0: atl1c: eth0 NIC Link is Up<100 Mbps Full Duplex>
[ 8217.651271] psmouse.c: resync failed, issuing reconnect request
[ 8219.160058] eth0: no IPv6 routers present
```

Comment: Some similar reports found in Debian & Gentoo world
http://lists.debian.org/debian-x/2011/04/msg00464.html
http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=61309
http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-871347-start-0.html

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 0):

There are some others facing difficulties with that chipset in Natty. Take a look at [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27537/broadcom-sta-driver-doesnt-work-well-with-bcm4313) for info on how to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a potential fix

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
// Make sure the following is added
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="i8042.nomux"
// Save the file and exit gedit
sudo update-grub
```

Only time will tell if mouse freezes up again. Just applied this setting 30 min ago, and I will wait for at least 72 hours before making comments

Comment: The fix is half way. On clean boot up, the workaround does address the mouse freeze issue; hence, I haven't run into issues with WiFi connection drop
However, if I put the netbook to hibernation or suspend, mouse would start freezing up again.

Comment: By the way, the issue remains in kernel 2.6.39-0-generic (installed from the PPA branch at the time of writing)