# How do i figure out why ubuntu is crashing on me randomly?

Tags: 11.04, wireless, drivers, dell

Ubuntu keeps crashing on me randomly. It just crashed 3 times in a row. Can someone please help me jolt down why.

When it crashes, the PC just freezes. Mouse pointer goes un-responsive and I have to do a hard reboot everytime.

The syslog was huge. system crashed at 23:45. I have uploaded it to pastebin.

[View system log](http://pastebin.com/buzNd0R6)

Thanks for any help.

I am using ubuntu 11.04 natty. Unity interface. kernel v 2.6.38-8-generic

**EDIT**

shafee@shafee-pc:~$ lspci | grep Network
04:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller (rev 01)

I on a dell n4010

Comment: Did your PC crash on other versions of Ubutntu/Windows?
What is the frequency of crashes? Could it be a hardware problem, overheating (it's hot now if you're on north hemisphere)?

Comment: it never crashed on windows 7. I just switched to ubuntu about 2 months ago. It crashes once or twice a week and sometimes, like today thrice in a row! Its not overheating, because if it were, wouldnt the PC shut itself off? and the air went is not that hot. i av updated question with ubuntu version

Comment: Are you using wifi and a browser when the crash occured?

Comment: Yeah. The first time i was working on chrome. The second time it happened just as i opened chrome. and i am on wifi :D i feel u av got my solution? :D :D

Comment: Hi Shafee could you paste this command in a terminal lspci | grep Network and add the output to your question. I believe it has something to do with the wireless driver being used if you could also add your computer model if it has one it will help narrow the list of suspects

Comment: I have added the requested info.

Comment: Please, check: http://askubuntu.com/questions/40725/random-freezes-followed-by-loss-of-wifi-connection-with-a-bcm4313-wireless-card

Comment: @Allan, I have the same issue on a brand new Acer. Firefox+Wireless. 03:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR928X Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01). Any solution? It does a reboot on me, without warning...

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).