# Regularly losing wifi connection

Tags: wireless, broadcom

I use Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver, but quite often the connection drops and connects shortly after again.

lspci -v | less:

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 145c
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
        Memory at 90100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: wl
        Kernel modules: wl, brcm80211
```

lshw -C network output:

```
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 02
       serial: 78:ac:c0:56:c6:79
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:42 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:90010000-90010fff memory:90000000-9000ffff memory:90020000-9002ffff
```

syslog output:

```
May 15 18:34:20 Notebook-Alexander wpa_supplicant[644]: Association request to the driver failed
May 15 18:34:21 Notebook-Alexander NetworkManager[566]:  (eth1): supplicant     connection state:  associating -> associated
May 15 18:34:21 Notebook-Alexander wpa_supplicant[644]: Associated with 06:24:fe:37:92:4b
May 15 18:34:21 Notebook-Alexander NetworkManager[566]:  (eth1): supplicant connection state:  associated -> 4-way handshake
May 15 18:34:21 Notebook-Alexander NetworkManager[566]:  (eth1): supplicant connection state:  4-way handshake -> group handshake
May 15 18:34:21 Notebook-Alexander wpa_supplicant[644]: WPA: Key negotiation completed with 06:24:fe:37:92:4b [PTK=TKIP GTK=TKIP]
May 15 18:34:21 Notebook-Alexander wpa_supplicant[644]: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 06:24:fe:37:92:4b completed (reauth) [id=13 id_str=]
May 15 18:34:21 Notebook-Alexander NetworkManager[566]:  (eth1): supplicant connection state:  group handshake -> completed
May 15 18:34:21 Notebook-Alexander NetworkManager[566]:  Activation (eth1/wireless) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.  Connected to wireless network 'FRITZ!Box Fon WLAN 7170-DH8'.
May 15 18:34:21 Notebook-Alexander NetworkManager[566]:  Activation (eth1) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) scheduled.
May 15 18:34:21 Notebook-Alexander NetworkManager[566]:  Activation (eth1) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) started...
May 15 18:34:21 Notebook-Alexander NetworkManager[566]:  (eth1): device state change: 5 -> 7 (reason 0)
May 15 18:34:21 Notebook-Alexander NetworkManager[566]:  Activation (eth1) Beginning DHCPv4 transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
May 15 18:34:21 Notebook-Alexander NetworkManager[566]:  dhclient started with pid 4824
May 15 18:34:21 Notebook-Alexander NetworkManager[566]:  Activation (eth1) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) complete.
May 15 18:34:21 Notebook-Alexander dhclient: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.1.1-P1
May 15 18:34:21 Notebook-Alexander dhclient: Copyright 2004-2010 Internet Systems Consortium.
May 15 18:34:21 Notebook-Alexander dhclient: All rights reserved.
May 15 18:34:21 Notebook-Alexander dhclient: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
May 15 18:34:21 Notebook-Alexander dhclient: 
May 15 18:34:21 Notebook-Alexander dhclient: Listening on LPF/eth1/ac:81:12:24:fa:29
May 15 18:34:21 Notebook-Alexander NetworkManager[566]:  (eth1): DHCPv4 state changed nbi -> preinit
May 15 18:34:21 Notebook-Alexander dhclient: Sending on   LPF/eth1/ac:81:12:24:fa:29
May 15 18:34:21 Notebook-Alexander dhclient: Sending on   Socket/fallback
May 15 18:34:21 Notebook-Alexander dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.178.27 on eth1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
May 15 18:34:21 Notebook-Alexander dhclient: DHCPACK of 192.168.178.27 from 192.168.178.1
May 15 18:34:21 Notebook-Alexander dhclient: bound to 192.168.178.27 -- renewal in 386587 seconds.
May 15 18:34:21 Notebook-Alexander NetworkManager[566]:  (eth1): DHCPv4 state changed preinit -> reboot
May 15 18:34:21 Notebook-Alexander NetworkManager[566]:  Activation (eth1) Stage 4 of 5 (IP4 Configure Get) scheduled...
May 15 18:34:21 Notebook-Alexander NetworkManager[566]:  Activation (eth1) Stage 4 of 5 (IP4 Configure Get) started...
May 15 18:34:21 Notebook-Alexander NetworkManager[566]:    address 192.168.178.27
May 15 18:34:21 Notebook-Alexander NetworkManager[566]:    prefix 24 (255.255.255.0)
May 15 18:34:21 Notebook-Alexander NetworkManager[566]:    gateway 192.168.178.1
May 15 18:34:21 Notebook-Alexander NetworkManager[566]:    nameserver '192.168.178.1'
May 15 18:34:21 Notebook-Alexander NetworkManager[566]:    domain name 'fritz.box'
May 15 18:34:21 Notebook-Alexander NetworkManager[566]:  Scheduling stage 5
May 15 18:34:21 Notebook-Alexander NetworkManager[566]:  Activation (eth1) Stage 5 of 5 (IP Configure Commit) scheduled...
May 15 18:34:21 Notebook-Alexander NetworkManager[566]:  Done scheduling stage 5
May 15 18:34:21 Notebook-Alexander NetworkManager[566]:  Activation (eth1) Stage 4 of 5 (IP4 Configure Get) complete.
May 15 18:34:21 Notebook-Alexander NetworkManager[566]:  Activation (eth1) Stage 5 of 5 (IP Configure Commit) started...
May 15 18:34:21 Notebook-Alexander avahi-daemon[548]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth1.IPv4 with address 192.168.178.27.
May 15 18:34:21 Notebook-Alexander avahi-daemon[548]: New relevant interface eth1.IPv4 for mDNS.
May 15 18:34:21 Notebook-Alexander avahi-daemon[548]: Registering new address record for 192.168.178.27 on eth1.IPv4.
May 15 18:34:22 Notebook-Alexander NetworkManager[566]:  (eth1): device state change: 7 -> 8 (reason 0)
May 15 18:34:22 Notebook-Alexander NetworkManager[566]:  Policy set 'Auto FRITZ!Box Fon WLAN 7170-DH8' (eth1) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
May 15 18:34:22 Notebook-Alexander NetworkManager[566]:  Activation (eth1) successful, device activated.
May 15 18:34:22 Notebook-Alexander NetworkManager[566]:  Activation (eth1) Stage 5 of 5 (IP Configure Commit) complete.
May 15 18:34:30 Notebook-Alexander ntpdate[4877]: adjust time server 91.189.94.4 offset 0.000983 sec
May 15 18:35:31 Notebook-Alexander wpa_supplicant[644]: Trying to associate with 00:1c:4a:d4:f1:1e (SSID='FRITZ!Box Fon WLAN 7170-DH8' freq=2437 MHz)
May 15 18:35:31 Notebook-Alexander NetworkManager[566]:  (eth1): supplicant connection state:  completed -> associating
May 15 18:35:31 Notebook-Alexander wpa_supplicant[644]: Association request to the driver failed
May 15 18:35:32 Notebook-Alexander wpa_supplicant[644]: Associated with 06:24:fe:37:92:4b
May 15 18:35:32 Notebook-Alexander NetworkManager[566]:  (eth1): supplicant connection state:  associating -> associated
May 15 18:35:32 Notebook-Alexander NetworkManager[566]:  (eth1): supplicant connection state:  associated -> 4-way handshake
May 15 18:35:32 Notebook-Alexander wpa_supplicant[644]: WPA: IE in 3/4 msg does not match with IE in Beacon/ProbeResp (src=06:24:fe:37:92:4b)
May 15 18:35:32 Notebook-Alexander NetworkManager[566]:  (eth1): supplicant connection state:  4-way handshake -> disconnected
May 15 18:35:32 Notebook-Alexander wpa_supplicant[644]: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=00:00:00:00:00:00 reason=0
May 15 18:35:35 Notebook-Alexander NetworkManager[566]:  (eth1): roamed from BSSID 06:24:FE:37:92:4B (FRITZ!Box Fon WLAN 7170-DH8) to (none) ((none))
May 15 18:35:37 Notebook-Alexander NetworkManager[566]:  (eth1): supplicant connection state:  disconnected -> scanning
May 15 18:35:38 Notebook-Alexander wpa_supplicant[644]: Trying to associate with 00:1c:4a:d4:f1:1e (SSID='FRITZ!Box Fon WLAN 7170-DH8' freq=2437 MHz)
May 15 18:35:38 Notebook-Alexander wpa_supplicant[644]: Association request to the driver failed
May 15 18:35:38 Notebook-Alexander NetworkManager[566]:  (eth1): supplicant connection state:  scanning -> associating
May 15 18:35:39 Notebook-Alexander wpa_supplicant[644]: Associated with 06:24:fe:37:92:4b
May 15 18:35:39 Notebook-Alexander NetworkManager[566]:  (eth1): supplicant connection state:  associating -> associated
May 15 18:35:39 Notebook-Alexander NetworkManager[566]:  (eth1): supplicant connection state:  associated -> 4-way handshake
May 15 18:35:39 Notebook-Alexander wpa_supplicant[644]: WPA: IE in 3/4 msg does not match with IE in Beacon/ProbeResp (src=06:24:fe:37:92:4b)
May 15 18:35:39 Notebook-Alexander NetworkManager[566]:  (eth1): supplicant connection state:  4-way handshake -> disconnected
May 15 18:35:39 Notebook-Alexander wpa_supplicant[644]: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=00:00:00:00:00:00 reason=0
May 15 18:35:44 Notebook-Alexander NetworkManager[566]:  (eth1): supplicant connection state:  disconnected -> scanning
May 15 18:35:44 Notebook-Alexander wpa_supplicant[644]: Trying to associate with 06:24:fe:37:92:4b (SSID='FRITZ!Box Fon WLAN 7170-DH8' freq=2437 MHz)
May 15 18:35:44 Notebook-Alexander wpa_supplicant[644]: Association request to the driver failed
May 15 18:35:44 Notebook-Alexander NetworkManager[566]:  (eth1): supplicant connection state:  scanning -> associating
May 15 18:35:45 Notebook-Alexander wpa_supplicant[644]: Associated with 06:24:fe:37:92:4b
May 15 18:35:45 Notebook-Alexander NetworkManager[566]:  (eth1): supplicant connection state:  associating -> associated
May 15 18:35:45 Notebook-Alexander NetworkManager[566]:  (eth1): supplicant connection state:  associated -> 4-way handshake
May 15 18:35:45 Notebook-Alexander NetworkManager[566]:  (eth1): supplicant connection state:  4-way handshake -> group handshake
May 15 18:35:45 Notebook-Alexander wpa_supplicant[644]: WPA: Key negotiation completed with 06:24:fe:37:92:4b [PTK=TKIP GTK=TKIP]
May 15 18:35:45 Notebook-Alexander wpa_supplicant[644]: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 06:24:fe:37:92:4b completed (reauth) [id=13 id_str=]
May 15 18:35:45 Notebook-Alexander NetworkManager[566]:  (eth1): supplicant connection state:  group handshake -> completed
May 15 18:35:47 Notebook-Alexander NetworkManager[566]:  (eth1): roamed from BSSID (none) ((none)) to 06:24:FE:37:92:4B (FRITZ!Box Fon WLAN 7170-DH8)
May 15 18:36:31 Notebook-Alexander wpa_supplicant[644]: Trying to associate with 00:1c:4a:d4:f1:1e (SSID='FRITZ!Box Fon WLAN 7170-DH8' freq=2437 MHz)
May 15 18:36:31 Notebook-Alexander wpa_supplicant[644]: Association request to the driver failed
May 15 18:36:31 Notebook-Alexander NetworkManager[566]:  (eth1): supplicant connection state:  completed -> associating
May 15 18:36:32 Notebook-Alexander wpa_supplicant[644]: Associated with 06:24:fe:37:92:4b
May 15 18:36:32 Notebook-Alexander NetworkManager[566]:  (eth1): supplicant connection state:  associating -> associated
May 15 18:36:32 Notebook-Alexander NetworkManager[566]:  (eth1): supplicant connection state:  associated -> 4-way handshake
May 15 18:36:32 Notebook-Alexander wpa_supplicant[644]: WPA: IE in 3/4 msg does not match with IE in Beacon/ProbeResp (src=06:24:fe:37:92:4b)
May 15 18:36:32 Notebook-Alexander wpa_supplicant[644]: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=00:00:00:00:00:00 reason=0
May 15 18:36:32 Notebook-Alexander NetworkManager[566]:  (eth1): supplicant connection state:  4-way handshake -> disconnected
May 15 18:36:35 Notebook-Alexander NetworkManager[566]:  (eth1): roamed from BSSID 06:24:FE:37:92:4B (FRITZ!Box Fon WLAN 7170-DH8) to (none) ((none))
May 15 18:36:37 Notebook-Alexander NetworkManager[566]:  (eth1): supplicant connection state:  disconnected -> scanning
May 15 18:36:38 Notebook-Alexander wpa_supplicant[644]: Trying to associate with 06:24:fe:37:92:4b (SSID='FRITZ!Box Fon WLAN 7170-DH8' freq=2437 MHz)
May 15 18:36:38 Notebook-Alexander wpa_supplicant[644]: Association request to the driver failed
May 15 18:36:38 Notebook-Alexander NetworkManager[566]:  (eth1): supplicant connection state:  scanning -> associating
May 15 18:36:39 Notebook-Alexander wpa_supplicant[644]: Associated with 06:24:fe:37:92:4b
May 15 18:36:39 Notebook-Alexander NetworkManager[566]:  (eth1): supplicant connection state:  associating -> associated
May 15 18:36:39 Notebook-Alexander NetworkManager[566]:  (eth1): supplicant connection state:  associated -> 4-way handshake
May 15 18:36:39 Notebook-Alexander NetworkManager[566]:  (eth1): supplicant connection state:  4-way handshake -> group handshake
May 15 18:36:39 Notebook-Alexander wpa_supplicant[644]: WPA: Key negotiation completed with 06:24:fe:37:92:4b [PTK=TKIP GTK=TKIP]
May 15 18:36:39 Notebook-Alexander wpa_supplicant[644]: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 06:24:fe:37:92:4b completed (reauth) [id=13 id_str=]
May 15 18:36:39 Notebook-Alexander NetworkManager[566]:  (eth1): supplicant connection state:  group handshake -> completed
May 15 18:36:39 Notebook-Alexander NetworkManager[566]:  (eth1): supplicant connection state:  completed -> group handshake
May 15 18:36:39 Notebook-Alexander wpa_supplicant[644]: WPA: Group rekeying completed with 06:24:fe:37:92:4b [GTK=TKIP]
May 15 18:36:39 Notebook-Alexander NetworkManager[566]:  (eth1): supplicant connection state:  group handshake -> completed
May 15 18:36:41 Notebook-Alexander NetworkManager[566]:  (eth1): roamed from BSSID (none) ((none)) to 06:24:FE:37:92:4B (FRITZ!Box Fon WLAN 7170-DH8)
```

Comment: You can post long log output to [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/).

Comment: There are quite a few questions relating to the BCM4313 chipset performance problems. Here's [one picked at random](http://askubuntu.com/questions/27537/broadcom-sta-driver-doesnt-work-well-with-bcm4313). Do a search on this site for BCM4313 and you'll find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to install some more recent wifi kernel modules. - They can come from Ubuntu repositories if you enable the [**backport repository**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports#Enabling%20the%20entire%20repository) on your system first.

If you are on **Maverick** install `linux-backports-modules-wireless-maverick-generic`.
If you are on **Natty** install `linux-backports-modules-cw-2.6.39-natty-generic`.