# How to fix BCM4312 driver problem?

Tags: wireless, broadcom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Broadcom STA driver doesn’t work well with BCM4313](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27537/broadcom-sta-driver-doesnt-work-well-with-bcm4313)

I have a Dell Laptop on which wireless is giving me problems.The card some times is detected and some times the card could not be detected.I noticed this problem started since I did suspend and resume of my laptop.

So I unistalled the Broadcomm STA driver and installed b43 then also things did not worked as expected.In a series of installation and unistallations of the wireless driver here things have got hotch potch.

The network icon on top right hand corner does not shows an option of wireless network.
lspci -vnn shows following

```
0c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1397 WLAN Mini-Card [1028:000c]
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 17
    Memory at f6900000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [58] Vendor Specific Information: Len=78 <?>
    Capabilities: [e8] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [d0] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [13c] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [16c] Power Budgeting <?>
    Kernel modules: ssb
```

My specifications

```
cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=11.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=oneiric
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 11.10"


uname -a
Linux rin 3.0.0-12-generic #20-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 7 14:56:25 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
--
0c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1397 WLAN Mini-Card [1028:000c]
    Kernel modules: ssb

rfkill list all
0: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

and lsmod output is following

[code]

```
rin@rin:~$ lsmod 
Module                  Size  Used by
bnep                   18436  2 
rfcomm                 47946  8 
parport_pc             36962  0 
ppdev                  17113  0 
binfmt_misc            17540  1 
btusb                  18600  2 
bluetooth             166112  23 bnep,rfcomm,btusb
joydev                 17693  0 
snd_hda_codec_idt      70553  1 
snd_hda_intel          33390  2 
snd_hda_codec         104802  2 snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_hda_intel
uvcvideo               72711  0 
snd_hwdep              13668  1 snd_hda_codec
usbhid                 47198  0 
videodev               93004  1 uvcvideo
hid                    95463  1 usbhid
v4l2_compat_ioctl32    17083  1 videodev
dell_wmi               12681  0 
sparse_keymap          13890  1 dell_wmi
snd_pcm                96755  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
snd_rawmidi            30547  1 snd_seq_midi
dell_laptop            13831  0 
dcdbas                 14490  1 dell_laptop
psmouse                73882  0 
s    erio_raw              13166  0 
i915                  566711  2 
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
drm_kms_helper         42558  1 i915
drm                   236330  3 i915,drm_kms_helper
i2c_algo_bit           13423  1 i915
snd_seq                61896  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_timer              29991  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_seq_device         14540  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
snd                    68266  13 snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
soundcore              12680  1 snd
wmi                    19256  1 dell_wmi
snd_page_alloc         18529  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
video                  19412  1 i915
lp                     17799  0 
parport                46562  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp
r8169                  52788  0
```

Here is output when I try to install b43-fwcutter

```
sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  b43-fwcutter
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/16.9 kB of archives.
After this operation, 90.1 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously deselected package b43-fwcutter.
(Reading database ... 129372 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking b43-fwcutter (from .../b43-fwcutter_1%3a014-9_amd64.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up b43-fwcutter (1:014-9) ...
```

and firmware

```
rin@rin:~$ sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  firmware-b43-installer
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/3,272 B of archives.
After this operation, 53.2 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously deselected package firmware-b43-installer.
(Reading database ... 129379 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking firmware-b43-installer (from .../firmware-b43-installer_1%3a014-9_all.deb) ...
Deleting old extracted firmware...
Setting up firmware-b43-installer (1:014-9) ...
An unsupported BCM4312 Low-Power (LP-PHY) device was found.
Use b43 LP-PHY firmware (firmware-b43-lpphy-installer package) instead.
Aborting.
```

There is no folder b43 in /lib/firmware  (for firmware etc.)

I am not sure as right now which driver is loaded and which one is working.Is there a way that without formatting the entire thing I can get it back on track?