# Cannot connect using wpa_supplicant

Tags: wireless, networking, command-line, wpa2, wpa-supplicant

I have set up a usb wifi dongle ( Ralink 148f:7601 ) and now I want to connect with it to my router.

I am using the following commands :

```
$ wpa_passphrase "SSID" "password"
```

then copy the `psk` I get to my config file:

```
ap_scan=1

network={
  ssid="SSID"
  scan_ssid=1
  proto=WPA2
  key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
  pairwise=CCMP TKIP
  group=CCMP TKIP
  psk=xxxxxxxx84f5ca1f640b21323682d51b7e880318e2da8813a6d4e9c8xxxxxxxx
  priority=5
}
```

and then `wpa_supplicant`

```
$ sudo wpa_supplicant -Dwext -ira0 -c ~/wpaconfig2 -d
```

I get the following log/errors http://paste.ubuntu.com/6955478/

Can someone direct me what am I doing wrong ?

**EDIT2**

I changed settings on the router to accept both `WPA-PSK` and `WPA2-PSK` and now I have the following;

and now I have the following log http://paste.ubuntu.com/6956230/ passing to the ASSOCIATED phase

```
ra0: Event ASSOCINFO (4) received                                                                                                                                                                              [25/1968]
ra0: Association info event
req_ies - hexdump(len=46): 00 0a 4e 4f 5f 54 4f 5f 41 43 54 41 01 08 82 84 8b 96 0c 12 18 24 dd 16 00 50 f2 01 01 00 00 50 f2 02 01 00 00 50 f2 02 01 00 00 50 f2 02
WPA: set own WPA/RSN IE - hexdump(len=24): dd 16 00 50 f2 01 01 00 00 50 f2 02 01 00 00 50 f2 02 01 00 00 50 f2 02
FT: Stored MDIE and FTIE from (Re)Association Response - hexdump(len=0):
ra0: Event ASSOC (0) received
ra0: State: ASSOCIATING -> ASSOCIATED
wpa_driver_wext_set_operstate: operstate 0->0 (DORMANT)
netlink: Operstate: linkmode=-1, operstate=5
ra0: Associated to a new BSS: BSSID=00:27:19:d0:xx:xx
ra0: No keys have been configured - skip key clearing
ra0: Associated with 00:27:19:d0:xx:xx
ra0: WPA: Association event - clear replay counter
ra0: WPA: Clear old PTK
EAPOL: External notification - portEnabled=0
EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized
EAPOL: External notification - portValid=0
EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized
EAPOL: External notification - EAP success=0
EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized
EAPOL: External notification - portEnabled=1
EAPOL: SUPP_PAE entering state CONNECTING
EAPOL: enable timer tick
EAPOL: SUPP_BE entering state IDLE
ra0: Setting authentication timeout: 10 sec 0 usec
ra0: Cancelling scan request
RTM_NEWLINK: operstate=0 ifi_flags=0x11003 ([UP][LOWER_UP])
RTM_NEWLINK, IFLA_IFNAME: Interface 'ra0' added
WEXT: if_removed already cleared - ignore event
Wireless event: cmd=0x8b15 len=20
Wireless event: new AP: 00:00:00:00:00:00
ra0: Event DISASSOC (1) received
ra0: Disassociation notification
ra0: WPA: Auto connect enabled: try to reconnect (wps=0)
ra0: Setting scan request: 0 sec 100000 usec
Added BSSID 00:27:19:d0:xx:xx into blacklist
ra0: Not rescheduling scan to ensure that specific SSID scans occur
ra0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=00:27:19:d0:xx:xx reason=0
ra0: Disconnect event - remove keys
wpa_driver_wext_set_key: alg=0 key_idx=0 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wpa_driver_wext_set_key: alg=0 key_idx=1 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wpa_driver_wext_set_key: alg=0 key_idx=2 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wpa_driver_wext_set_key: alg=0 key_idx=3 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wpa_driver_wext_set_key: alg=0 key_idx=4 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wpa_driver_wext_set_key: alg=0 key_idx=5 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wpa_driver_wext_set_key: alg=0 key_idx=0 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
ra0: State: ASSOCIATED -> DISCONNECTED
```

**EDIT**

Association dump in wireshark plaintext http://paste.ubuntu.com/6956275/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized" propably means that your Wifi Router disallow you to send any packages towards the Wifi Router. I saw something similar in a EAP/TTLS Wifi setup. There the Router dropped all the packages away because of different key knowledge on both sides (Pairwise Masterkey). It would be helpfull if you could take some traces with Wireshark to check the EAPOL protocol messages.  Probably a key exchange between Wifi Router and your wifi dongle fails.

Comment: I have updated the answer and if possible I will somehow post the Wireshark pcap file.

Comment: Because of the "Disassociation Notification"  for me it looks like an issue on the Wifi Router but nevertheless post your wpa_supplicant version with wpa_supplicant -v and re-check the settings on the Wifi Router. Then increase debugging verbosity on wpa_supllicant with wpa_supplicant -dd

Comment: Adding verbosity with `-dd` doesn't change much (almost anything). Version `wpa_supplicant v1.0
Copyright (c) 2003-2012, Jouni Malinen <j@w1.fi> and contributors`. With regards to router I don't know what should I check. I can connect to it with my laptop and it's set as I noted: for `WPA-PSK/WPA2-PSK`, encryption `TKIP`.

Comment: I suggest you use the far simpler method here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/421830/problems-working-with-broadcom-4352-wireless-card/421919#421919

Comment: @chili555 Eventually I got this to work by reinstalling the drivers with `sudo rmmod mt7601Usta; sudo modprobe mt7601Usta` and then rebooting the system. I have also `managed=false` `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`