# Getting function keys working on Samsung RV510 notebook

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, samsung, function-keys

I installed 10.10 on my Samsung RV510 notebook, but the function keys don't work. When I use them it seems as if they get locked on, and it becomes impossible to click things in the upper toolbar. Does anyone know of any drivers, or a way to get these to work? I do **not** want to go back to Windows.

Comment: Seems similar to [my issue on a Samsung Q330](http://askubuntu.com/questions/27534/fn-key-sticks-down)

Comment: I got a similar problem. When I press the fn key + F8 (increase volume) for excample, then the release action never gets triggered and my complete system is useless, as I can't use the keyboard properly anymore. The only thing that helps is to press the powerbutton and make a restart. Im just switching from windows to Ubuntu as well. I like it all, but it's really not too easy to keep in mind to never touch the fn keys. I got a Samsung Laptop and tried the above method like this: 1.) -> Here I only put in the specific model of my laptop > ENV{DMI_VENDOR}=="[sS][aA][mM][sS][uU][nN][gG]*",
> ATT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are two main problems, i had too and i fixed this way:

1) you have to force release of the keys (search internet)
   Pratically you have to add your exaxct pc model name to the file
   /lib/udev/rules.d/95-keyboard-force-release.rules

to take exact name of the pc run:

```
sudo dmidecode -s system-product-name
```

Then add the model like this on the file:

```
ENV{DMI_VENDOR}=="[sS][aA][mM][sS][uU][nN][gG]*", ATTR{[dmi/id]product_name}=="*N128*|*N130*|*N140*|*N210*|*N220*|*SR70S/SR71S*|*YOURMODEL*", 
RUN+="keyboard-force-release.sh $devpath samsung-other"
```

2) Install voria's samsung-backlight module:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1673864

Hope is useful.

Andrea.

Comment: I followed your instructions, and the keys work now, but I don't think I installed backlight properly because the brightness doesn't change with the keys. The link mentioned something to do with GRUB but I'm not sure what to do. Can you help any further?

Answer (score 2):

Edit:  I just made the Fn keys work!

You don't need the script (..what a good finding) so you did success to:

- Made the keys works? (OK)
- Installed backlight module? (OK)

Now just modify the grub file:

in a terminal write:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

(Insert your password)

Then modify the 8th line like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

Then save the file (CTRL + O) and exit (CTRL + X)

then write:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Now reebot your pc (..Finger crossed) your Fn + UP and Fn + Down will work!

Comment: Thanks @andrea! everything working fine! now if only i could get edge scroll to work, i'll be perfectly happy!

Comment: you can use the multitouch (two fingers) scroll i think even better.. i give you more details on your other post!

Answer (score 1):

well, if the keys now work you did the half work good. Damn samsung RV510! :)

I didn't made the modification to grub but i just remembered that i made a script to modify the file (of backlight module) that contain the value of the brightness..

When you press the Fn + Up or Fn + Down the value of backlight is changed in this file:

/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness (that contains a number 0 - 7)

Instead you need to modify this file with a script to change value of backlight:

`/sys/class/backlight/samsung/brightness`  <-- this works

So, now your problem is only to do a script that modify the file and then associate to a shortcut like CTRL + Up and CTRL + Down (I didn't success to use the Fn key)

If can help, i made the script "like" this with the proper modifications mensioned before:

```
http://jaub.wordpress.com/2010/06/05/script-regolazione-luminosita-lcd-per-ubuntu-lucid/
```

PS: do NOT come back to windows! :)