# Screen brighness control doesn't work on a Samsung Netbook NN150Plus

Tags: 11.10, brightness, samsung

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting function keys working on Samsung RV510 notebook](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28017/getting-function-keys-working-on-samsung-rv510-notebook)

I have just updated to 11.10 form 11.04. I use a Samsung NN150Plus netbook and have no control over the screen brightness. If I use the keyboard keys its either full brightness or on minimum. If I use the system settings/display, it freaks out and runs from low to high without any control. This is a major issue and makes the netbook almost unusable.

Comment: Note for moderators: This question has already been asked in question 67262. While, the HW isn't exactly the same, it's caused by the same bug and thus has the same workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

Add this ppa https://launchpad.net/~voria/+archive/ppa using software sources and install Voria samsung-backlight, reboot and you should be good.

Comment: Great, did as instructed and worked fine, thanks much appreciated, a real life saver!