# How do I fix the brightness on a Samsung Aura R700 Dillen?

Tags: 11.10, nvidia, xorg, brightness, samsung

My Problem: Since Ubuntu 10.04 I can no longer adjust the background brightness of the built in LCD-Panel. The Laptop (Samsung Aura R700 Dillen - Nvidia 8600M GT GPU) is always on a very low brightness-level. Since Ubuntu 11.04 the below detailed solution doesn't work any more.

In Ubuntu **10.04** the solution to the backlight problem was rather "simple":

1. Open nvidia-settings and create/save and merge a xorg.conf file.
2. Open a Terminal and: `sudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf`
3. Once opened, in the "Device" section, add this line: `Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"`
4. Save and exit. Reboot the machine.
5. Done.

I want to do the *same* thing in Ubuntu 11.10, because this takes care of the brightness-adjust problem.**

How can I *safely* create and edit xorg.conf in Ubuntu 11.10? I can't find it and a lot of ppl suggest different methods how to create it again. Some are known to cause the computer to not boot correctly.

- Adding the Voria-Tools PPA is **not** an option. I don't like installing untrusted PPA's. Also, I tried this before and it never worked.
- I have [tried the steps](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28017/getting-function-keys-working-on-samsung-rv510-notebook) mentioned in the link Oli posted. A few of those steps made Ubuntu hang during bootup (editing Grub to add the ACPI-line for example; it always typed in something different - something was buggy there).

Comment: About half the questions on this site are related to Samsung backlight issues. Have you tried any of the fixed suggested in any of them? Here's [one that worked for me](http://askubuntu.com/questions/28017/getting-function-keys-working-on-samsung-rv510-notebook) (the udev method). Let me know and if it does and I'll close this as a dupe.

Comment: Hi Oli, yes, I have tried the steps mentioned in the link you posted. A few of those steps made Ubuntu hang during bootup (editing Grub to add the ACPI-line for example; it always typed in something different - something was buggy there). I have also tried the Voria-Tools - without success. I tried a lot of different things, but none of them worked and caused other problems. A few days ago, I installed Ubuntu again and started fresh. So, in order to keep things clean this time, I'd like to stick to what I know works best (the steps mentioned in my Post, but for 11.10). Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally fixed it! And even - without - the need of any Voria-Tools PPA or without the need to manually edit anything else, besides what I already posted. I have tried this on **three** Samsung Laptops - with success. All of them had the same issue (with brightness controls).

**SOLUTION (for Ubuntu 11.04 and 11.10):**

1. Open nvidia-settings (you can find it via Unity-Dash)
2. Go to "X Server Display Configuration"
3. Click on "Save to X Configuration File"
4. It will display an error: `Failed to parse existing X config file ‘/etc/X11/xorg.conf’!`
5. Ignore the error. A new window pops up and asks you to **save** the X Configuration File.
6. Leave everything as it is (`/etc/X11/xorg.conf` - do not merge, if you haven't done this before) and click on save. This will generate a new file for you.
7. Open this new file with: `gksudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf`
8. Once the file is opened, do what I mentioned in my previous Post: **Add** this line to the `Device` section of the file:

   ```
   Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
   ```

```
from this                        TO   this
```

```
Section "Device"                  | Section "Device"
 Identifier "Device0"             |   Identifier  "Device0"
 Driver     "nvidia"              |   Driver      "nvidia"
 VendorName "NVIDIA Corporation"  |   VendorName  "NVIDIA Corporation"
                                  |   Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
EndSection                        | EndSection
```

9. Click on save and close the window.
10. Reboot the machine. Brightness-controls should now be working and you should be able to use your FN-Keys to adjust brightness.